# Help with Combination

Tags: permutations, combinations

Guys need help to solve this one..
How will we arrange  Red balls in '$N$' places , so that if you choose any '$M$' consecutive places, there should be at least '$K$' Red balls among this '$M$' chosen places.And we should use minimum number of Red balls.

Now, If $N = 6$ and $M = 3$ and $K = 2$ then, one combination is like '$1\,\; R\,\; R\,\; 1\; R\; R\; 1$' Here if we choose any $3$ consecutive places, there will be $2$ Red Balls. So like that how many ways we can do it..

There could be a larger numbers also.
Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised to answer the general question:**

Assume first that $n=3m$, so that we may segment the string into $m$ blocks of three balls. Each block must be of one of the forms RRW, RWR, and WRR, and a string of $m$ RRW blocks is certainly acceptable, so there must be $2m$ red and $m$ white balls.

Let $s_m$ be the number of acceptable strings of $3m$ balls. Suppose that I have such a string. If it ends with a WRR block, I can append any of the three kinds of block to get an acceptable string of length $3(m+1)$. If it ends with an RWR block, I can append either an RWR or an RRW block, but not a WRR block. And if it ends with an RRW block, I can only append another RRW block. To turn it around, a WRR block can only follow another WRR block; an RWR block can follow a WRR block or another RWR block; and an RRW block can follow anything.

Let $r_m$ be the number of acceptable strings of length $3m$ that end with an RRW block, $c_m$ the number that end with an RWR block, and $\ell_m$ the number that end with a WRR block. Then from the last paragraph we see that

$$\begin{align*}
s_m&=r_m+c_m+\ell_m\;,\\
r_m&=s_{m-1}\;,\\
c_m&=c_{m-1}+\ell_{m-1}\;,\text{ and}\\
\ell_m&=\ell_{m-1}\;.
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

Clearly $r_1=c_1=\ell_1=1$, so $\ell_m=1$ for all $m\ge 1$, and $(1)$ reduces to

$$\begin{align*}
s_m&=r_m+c_m+1\;,\\
r_m&=s_{m-1}\;,\text{ and}\\
c_m&=c_{m-1}+1\;.\\
\end{align*}\tag{2}$$

From the last line of $(2)$ it’s clear that $c_m=m$ for all $m\ge 1$, so $$s_m=s_{m-1}+m+1\;.\tag{3}$$ If we set $s_0=1$ and $r_0=c_0=0$, the recurrences are all valid for $m\ge 1$, and it’s not hard to verify that

$$s_m=\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}=\frac12(m+1)(m+2)=\binom{m+2}2\;.$$

This completely answers the question when $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

Now suppose that $n=3m+1$. There is an acceptable string of length $3m$ ending in WRR, namely, a string of $m$ WRR blocks; we can append a white ball to this string, so there is an acceptable string of length $n$ with just $2m$ red balls. However, this is the **only** such string, since, as we saw before, a WRR block must follow another WRR block, and so on back to the beginning of the string. Thus, there is only one acceptable string of length $n=3m+1$ that uses the minimum possible number of red balls: $(\text{WRR})^m\text{W}$.

Finally, suppose that $n=3m+2$. Clearly at least one of the last two balls must be red, and one suffices, since we can append a red ball to the string $(\text{WRR})^m\text{W}$, so the minimum possible number of red balls in this case is $2m+1$. We can append WR to an acceptable string of length $3m$ if and only if the string is $(\text{WRR})^m$; that accounts for one acceptable string of length $n$. We can append RW to any acceptable string of length $3m$ that ends in RWR or WRR. There is just one of the latter, and there are $c_m=m$ of the former, so this case accounts for another $m+1$ acceptable strings of length $n$. Thus, there are $m+2$ acceptable strings of length $n=3m+2$.

Comment: Thanks for you help Brian M. Scott,  Yeah that is absolutely right. But What I need is to Formulate this one. I mean for small number we can enumerating the permissible arrangements. But for large number say 100 places, at that time what approach will we fallow.. as observing all arrangements of Red balls in 100 places and then filtering out the valid one is heavy.

Comment: @user79981: In that case you should probably edit your question, which in its present form doesn’t give any indication that you want a more general solution.

Comment: Ok..thanks. Have corrected the question now.

Comment: @user79981: I’ll give it some thought, but probably not until after I’ve had some sleep.